# a character or symbol can not be represented by a char data type in java language

Tags: java

Is there a character or symbol that can not be represented using a java primitive **char** data type? 
please show me an example and how to find those characters or symbols, thanks.

[edit]
is there a chinese character that can not be represented by a **char** type, like char c = '中' is ok.

Comment: Java strings are implicitly UTF-16 if I recall correctly, and strings are themselves implemented by a `char[]`, so the answer to your question is probably no.

Comment: Anything outside the Unicode [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)) cannot be represented by a single `char`.

Comment: Define “character”, because AFAIK all “characters” have a 16-bit char code, which means “no”.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not that it really matters but Java strings are either Latin-1 or UTF-16, they switch internally. And then they are `byte[]`, `toCharArray()` is not `O(1)`.

Comment: UTF-16 is a variable byte-length encoding. The character `中` needs more than a single `char` to be represented. It consists of `2`. See `System.out.println("中".length());` or `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("中".toCharArray()));`.

Answer (score 4):

The terms "character" and "symbol" have overloaded meanings, and probably should be avoided if you are trying to be precise in your meaning.  It is better to talk about Unicode code-points.  (A code-point is a standard representation for a symbol.)

The G-clef symbol  has a Unicode code-point (U+1D12E) that cannot be expressed as a 16 bit character<sup>1</sup>.  Two 16 bit character (i.e. `char`) values are used to represent this in UTF-16, which is what is the encoding *model* that is used by Java strings<sup>2</sup>.  (In this case the characters are U+D834 and U+DD1E)

Emojis are a more common example.

In general, any Unicode code-point outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) range U+0000 to U+FFFF requires two `char` values to represent it.

The chinese ideograph 中 is code-point U+4E2D.  It is in the BMP and requires one 16-bit character.

If you want example of CJK characters (ideographs) outside of the BMP, there are literally thousands of them in code planes 1 and 2.  Unfortunately, most of them don't have corresponding glyphs in typical fonts, so they won't *display* properly.  If you are looking for examples that have glyphs, I suggest that you search the Unicode "code plane" pages for:

- [Plane 1 - the Supplementary Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane)
- [Plane 2 - the Supplementary Ideographic Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Ideographic_Plane)

Since the characters shown in these pages will be rendered using *your* browser using *your* installed fonts, you should be able to see which ones render to recognizable characters on your computer.

---

<sup>1 - I chose this as an example because it is widely used in western music notation, and likely to have a glyph in a typical font.</sup>

<sup>2 - Actually, the `String` class models text as either UTF-16 `char` values or Unicode codepoints.  The actual representation is even more nuanced, but this is beyond the scope of this Question.</sup>